# In which stack exchange should I post this Base64 question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding Base64.

> "Why isn't the code 'hellooo=' a valid Base64 code?"

In which Stack Exchange site should I post such a question? Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not sure which tags to use. Could somebody please help with that?

Comment: It depends on the question, not just the topic. Such a question _could_ also be on-topic on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. It's hard to tell when we don't know what you want to ask.

Comment: Don't you think most questions about [base64 are already asked](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=base64)?

Comment: The question is, "Why isn't the code 'hellooo=' a valid Base64 code?"

Comment: What is the problem? My first test shows it is valid

Comment: @Someone It is.

Comment: Then is there something wrong with Python's `base64` module in OnlineGDB?

Comment: We can't tell because you keep us guessing (and you see both Art and I are pretty good at it). So you obviously have some python code with a specific library where you have as input that base64 string and then get either an error or output you don't expect? Is that your actual question?

Comment: OnlineGDB says it is for C++. Where does Python come from?

Comment: I get an "incorrect padding" error from the `base64` module, and no edit on the padding fixes it. I just keep getting errors

Comment: They haven't changed the description, but it has more languages and doesn't even have C/C++ as default.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22incorrect+padding%22&mixed=0

Answer (score 12):

If it is an programming problem you might ask on Stack Overflow.

A quick search already revealed that [base64](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=base64) is not a niche topic. On the SE network a whopping 130K questions are already asked about base64 in one form or the other.

It is relevant that you include for the type of question you're about to ask:

- the exact code you're using,
- which input / test case you have tried
- what the expected output is
- what the actual output
- what the exact error text is (both from the compiler (if any) or at runtime).

Screenshots of code and error messages will not do.

In your case this means including you're using OnlineGDB which advertizes it uses Python 3. Also relevant which library (version) you included and how you did that.

Stack Overflow has extensive guidance in the Help center for [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as references at the end to external resources that are all worth reading and applying that advice to your actual question.

Don't forget to leverage the on-site search to find [`[python] "incorrect padding"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22incorrect+padding%22&mixed=0) similar questions and study their answers. You can mention the answers you tried to narrow down your problem.

Do not ask your question if one or more duplicates exists. The answers found should be enough to work out where your problem is. Only if that is not the case a new question focusing on the hurdle implementing one or more of those answer should be asked.

Just for what it is worth. I tried this code (I have no idea what I'm doing):

```python
import base64

print(base64.b64decode('hellooo='))
```

and that outputs

> b'\x85\xe9e\xa2\x8a'

without throwing the error you describe.

For completeness this is what it looks like for me in [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) with Python3 selected as language.

[image]

So make sure you include your actual code.